# IP aggregation and finding correct network id

Tags: networking, ip-address

I'm having trouble understanding how IP aggregation works and also which IP addresses "belong" together. So I have this forwarding table below, same output port.

```
Network ID  ` Net mask
10.0.0.128  ` 255.255.255.128 or /25
10.0.0.0    ` 255.255.255.128 or /25
10.0.1.0    ` 255.255.255.0 or /24
10.0.4.0    ` 255.255.254.0 or /23
10.0.2.0    ` 255.255.254.0 or /23
```

How do I go about aggregating and how do I find what the id is for the network to which, for example, the address 10.0.0.213 belongs?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking, but I'll try to answer. To my (limited) knowledge, you are concerned with the mask of the address. This gives you the IP block which the address is part of. Thus, attempting to find where 10.0.0.213 belongs, by eliminating based on mask, the `10.0.(1,4,2).*` blocks, you are left with 10.0.(128,0).* blocks. These 2 left over blocks seem redundant only if they are separated based on some network interface e.g. `eth0` having a mask of `255.255.255.128`  or `/25`having a range of `10.0.0.(0-128)` and `eth1` with `/24` and range `10.0.0.(128-255)`

Comment: In essesence, the mask of the second line appears to be wrong. I would correct it being `10.0.0.0   255.255.255.128 or /25` to `10.0.0.0     255.255.255.0 or /24`. Use https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr if you need help with this. A very good tool.

Comment: @cybex the second line is correct. It refers to 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.127

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whatyou are asking.

IP aggregation in the idea of taking small ranges of IPs and combining them into a larger block.

The ranges you have listed are non overlapping and sequential, so those 5 blocks can all be aggregated into a block 10.0.[0-4].x

The smallest block which will cover all these ranges is thus 10.0.0.0/22 =  netmask 255.255.252.0 Any netmask smaller or equal to /22 will include all thise ranges.

10.0.2.213 belongs to the network  10.0.2.0 /255.255.254.0 or /23

You can understand better by converting the netmasks into binary. 255= 11111111 - 8 x 1s.  /x is simply counting the 1s (which should always be on the left).

To find the network(s) an IP address belongs in you convert it to binary and then "or" the bits

```
  00001010.0000000.00000010.1101010 /10.0.2.213
  11111111.1111111.11111110.0000000 /255.255.254.0
  ------------------------------------------------
  11111111.1111111.11111110.1101010 which is greater then 1111111.1111111.1111110.000000 so it is in the network. If it was smaller it would be outside the network. (I think - I dont normally do it this way in my head!)
```